# Can't initiate GLFW with Code::Blocks on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, codeblocks, glfw

Believe me, I've searched for answers, but I just can't seem to solve this problem:

When I try to start a **GLFW 2.7** project using **CodeBlocks 10.05**, I always get errors when pointing to the directory where it's installed: (C:\glfw-2.7)

> This directory seems valid, but this wizard cannot locate the following GLFW library file: glfw in it. (Also tried prepending lin & appending .a & .lib)

I've tried copying gl.h from the ./include/GL folder into both the 'include' & the root 'glfw-2.7' folder. I've also tried copying files from lib/win32 into the parent 'lib' folder. No matter what, this so-called "wizard" can't find the files it needs.

Anyone know what else I can try? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I found the answer I was looking for: I needed to locate libglfw.a for MinGW & put it in the include folder. Live & learn.

Comment: What do you mean by "for MinGW"?

Comment: Honestly, this was so long ago, I don't recall perfectly. I think I just needed to point to a source file.